# Issue importing android studio project to Android studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

i have previously created an application using Android Studio 1.3 and recently i have updated it to 2.0 and when i try to import project using import existing android studio project, it gets stuck on 'Building  gradle project info' screen. Can someone tell me whats the issue? TIA

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: This is because of missing some dependencies or new android studio try to update the dependencies, Wait until completion